# Automatic lettrine in chapters

Tags: macros, memoir, lettrine

I'm trying to get lettrine dropcaps applied automatically on the first word of each chapter. I found some code here: http://dererumnatura.us/archives/2009/02/automatic-usage.html which I've tried adapting:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{ifthen}

% from the above link:
\newcommand*{\ecap}[1]{\begingroup\obeyspaces\etospace{#1}{}}
\newcommand*{\etospace}[3]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{\space}}%
{\endgroup\lettrine{#1}{#2}#3}{\etospace{#1}{#2#3}}}

% my attempt at:
\renewcommand\memendofchapterhook{\ecap}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
 in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

The above works, but not if I put linebreaks after `\chapter{Test}`... Is there a way to get a command to ignore the newlines preceding its arguments?

Comment: You would have to explicitly code the space following the first word if you did this. At least, I think so. A new line is a space, after all ... I suppose you could apply the ifthenelse only after the first character. Make the macro take 2 arguments. Take the first, then apply the tweak to the second ...

Comment: I think it’s a bad idea to automate lettrines: `lhang` and other such parameters need to be set differently for different letters for optically correct results.

Comment: @Thérèse: This is just a minimal example, I'm changing the font as well as other things & it looks fine to my eye with identical commands for each chapter regardless of the word. Anyway, could you elaborate, @cfr? I'm a bit of a novice still...

Comment: http://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-4/fine-typography/raised-and-dropped-initials suggests some of what I meant by optically correct results; using lettrines well is an art.

Comment: the use of \obeyspaces there is distinctly odd (and complicates skipping over the white space as you ask, since it is trying to enforce exactly the opposite)

Comment: So I acknowledge that it might be a bad idea, but how would it be done? Please give me a gun so I can shoot myself in the foot :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using explicitly `\lettrine`: you gain little in trying to make the thing automatic.

Anyway, here's a proof of concept.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just to get smaller pictures, like oneside

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewCommandCopy{\latexchapter}{\chapter}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{sO{#3}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\latexchapter{#3}}{\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}
  \peek_regex_replace_once:nn
   { [\s\c{par}]* (\c{label}\{.*?\})?? [\s\c{par}]* ([[:alpha:]]) ([[:alpha:]]*) \s* }
   { \1 \c{lettrine}\{\2\}\{\3\} \c{space} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{First, no label and no blank lines}
Once upon a time

\chapter{Second, no label and blank lines}

Once upon a time

\chapter{Third, with label and no blank lines}\label{a}
Once upon a time

\chapter{Third, with label and blank lines}\label{b}

Once upon a time

\chapter{Fourth, with label and blank lines}
\label{c}

Once upon a time

\end{document}
```

[image]

What can go wrong? Several things, which is the reason I classify this as “proof of concept”.

Comment: Exactly, several things can go wrong. Drop cap often looks bad in some situations: short first line or two, chapter beginning with dialogue (quotation marks), and other things. Best to do it manually. In fact, if the purpose is writing fiction, drop caps are nearly obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

Use a wrapper command rather than stringing together lower-level commands and then trying to modify their interaction(s) afterwards.

A wrapper command, here `\xchapter`, wrapping `\chapter` and a lettrine-ing command (`\xlettrine`) that processes the first token following the wrapping command, can have arbitrary code inserted between the two "internal" wrapped commands.

```
\newcommand\xchapter[1]{\xletttextdiv\chapter{#1}CODE HERE\xlettrine} text
```

`\chapter` already inserts its own spacing, though.

`\xlettrine` uses expl3 key=value settings to allow easy user-modifications.

e.g.,

```
\xchapter{Default}[legacy-font=true]{Once upon a time} \xlettrinehelptext
```

produces:

[image: default]

Adjusting some of the options

```
\xchapter{Example: Yinit}[
legacy-font=false,
font=\fsample\huge\color{red},
initial-kern=-0.7em,
indent-buffer=0.8em,
line-buffer=1,
vspace-factor=-1.1,
]{Continuation}   \xlettrinehelptext
```

produces:

[image: different settings]

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setmainfont{NotoSerif}

\newcommand\ffontname{Yinit}
\newfontfamily\fsample{\ffontname}[Scale=4]

\newcommand\xletttextdiv{\ \par
\noindent
:\hfill\rule{0.32\textwidth}{0.5pt}\hfill :
\par}

\newcommand\xlettrinehelptext{%
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  xx x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  xx x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  xx x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  xx x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  xx x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  xx x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  xx x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  xx x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  xx x x x x x x 
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x  xx x x x x x x 
}

\newcommand\xchapter[1]{\xletttextdiv\chapter{#1}\xlettrine}



    
\ExplSyntaxOn


\bool_new:N \l_xlett_legacyfont_bool % true for legacy fonts
\fp_new:N \l_xlett_vfactor_fp % how much of lettrine to move para up by, e.g., -1.3 times
\tl_new:N \l_xlett_font_tl % for legacy fonts, e.g., \input Acorn.fd
\dim_new:N \l_xlett_font_size_dim % for legacy fonts, e.g., 60pt
\dim_new:N \l_xlett_font_baselineskip_dim % for legacy fonts, e.g., 72pt
\tl_new:N \l_xlett_font_type_tl % for legacy fonts, e.g., T1
\tl_new:N \l_xlett_font_family_tl % for legacy fonts, e.g., Acorn
\tl_new:N \l_xlett_font_series_tl % for legacy fonts, e.g., m
\tl_new:N \l_xlett_font_shape_tl % for legacy fonts, e.g., n
\tl_new:N \l_xlett_firstword_tl
\tl_new:N \l_xlett_initial_tl

\dim_new:N \l_xlett_initkern_dim % of first word's tail, e.g., -0.3em
\dim_new:N \l_xlett_indentbuffer_dim % space around lettrine, e.g., 0.4em





\keys_define:nn { xlettrine }
  {
    legacy-font .bool_set:N = \l_xlett_legacyfont_bool,
    legacy-font .default:n = false,
    legacy-font .initial:n = false,

    font .tl_set:N = \l_xlett_font_tl,
    font .default:n = {\input Acorn.fd},
    font .initial:n = {\input Acorn.fd},

    font-size .dim_set:N =\l_xlett_font_size_dim,
    font-size .default:n = {60pt},
    font-size .initial:n = {60pt},

    font-baselineskip .dim_set:N =\l_xlett_font_baselineskip_dim,
    font-baselineskip .default:n = {72pt},
    font-baselineskip .initial:n = {72pt},
    
%       \fontsize{60pt}{72pt}\usefont{U}{Acorn}{xl}{n}
    font-type .tl_set:N = \l_xlett_font_type_tl,
    font-family .tl_set:N = \l_xlett_font_family_tl,
    font-series .tl_set:N = \l_xlett_font_series_tl,
    font-shape .tl_set:N = \l_xlett_font_shape_tl,

    font-type .default:n = U,
    font-family .default:n = Acorn,
    font-series .default:n = xl,
    font-shape .default:n = n,
        
    font-type .initial:n = U,
    font-family .initial:n = Acorn,
    font-series .initial:n = xl,
    font-shape .initial:n = n,

    initial-kern .dim_set:N = \l_xlett_initkern_dim,
    initial-kern .default:n = { -0.5em },
    initial-kern .initial:n = { -0.5em },

    indent-buffer .dim_set:N = \l_xlett_indentbuffer_dim,
    indent-buffer .default:n = {0.4em},
    indent-buffer .initial:n = {0.4em},
        
    line-buffer .int_set:N = \l_xlett_linebuffer_int,
    line-buffer .default:n = { 2 },
    line-buffer .initial:n = { 2 },
        
    vspace-factor .fp_set:N = \l_xlett_vfactor_fp,
    vspace-factor .default:n = { -1.3 },
    vspace-factor .initial:n = { -1.3 },
        
    %    help .code:n = { \xlettrinehelp },
    
  }



\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_remove_once:Nn { No }


\NewDocumentCommand { \xlettlm } {  } {
    \leftskip \dim_eval:n {\l_xlett_indentbuffer_dim + \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box}
}



\NewDocumentCommand { \xlettrineset } { o } {

    \keys_set:nn { xlettrine } { #1 } 
        }
        


\NewDocumentCommand { \xlettrine } { o m } {


        \tl_if_novalue:nF{#1}
        {\keys_set:nn { xlettrine } { #1 } }
            



    \tl_set:Nx 
        \l_xlett_firstword_tl  %Qwerty
        { #2 }
    \tl_set:Nx 
        \l_xlett_initial_tl   %Q
        { 
            \tl_item:Nn 
                \l_xlett_firstword_tl
                { 1 }
         }
    \tl_remove_once:No
        \l_xlett_firstword_tl   %werty
        { \l_xlett_initial_tl }
         
    \bool_if:NTF
    \l_xlett_legacyfont_bool
    {
    \hbox_set:Nn
        \l_tmpa_box
        {
        \group_begin:
        \tl_use:N
            \l_xlett_font_tl
            %   \input Acorn.fd
        \fontsize
            { \dim_use:N \l_xlett_font_size_dim }
            { \dim_use:N \l_xlett_font_baselineskip_dim }
            
        \usefont
            { \tl_use:N \l_xlett_font_type_tl }
            { \tl_use:N \l_xlett_font_family_tl }
            { \tl_use:N \l_xlett_font_series_tl }
            { \tl_use:N \l_xlett_font_shape_tl }
        \l_xlett_initial_tl
        \group_end:

        } 
        } % legacy font

    { % fontspec font
    \hbox_set:Nn
        \l_tmpa_box
        {
        \group_begin:
            \tl_use:N
                \l_xlett_font_tl
            \l_xlett_initial_tl
        \group_end:
        } 
        } % fontspec font

    
    \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
    \vspace{ \fp_use:N \l_xlett_vfactor_fp \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box}
    \hangindent=\dim_eval:n {\l_xlett_indentbuffer_dim + \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box}
    \hangafter=-\fp_to_int:n { \l_xlett_linebuffer_int + \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box / \baselineskip }
    \noindent
    \kern  \dim_use:N \l_xlett_initkern_dim
    \textsc{ \tl_use:N \l_xlett_firstword_tl }
}


\ExplSyntaxOff




\begin{document}

\xchapter{Default}[legacy-font=true]{Once upon a time} \xlettrinehelptext
\begin{verbatim}
legacy-font=true,
\end{verbatim}


%=============
\xchapter{Example: Yinit}[
legacy-font=false,
font=\fsample\huge\color{red},
initial-kern=-0.7em,
indent-buffer=0.8em,
line-buffer=1,
vspace-factor=-1.1,
]{Continuation}   \xlettrinehelptext

\begin{verbatim}
legacy-font=false,
font=\fsample\huge\color{red},
initial-kern=-0.7em,
indent-buffer=0.8em,
line-buffer=1,
vspace-factor=-1.1,
\end{verbatim}


\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: 10k is in reach :)